# My phone doesn't show xml of the app as it should

Tags: android, xml

i have a problem with xml design of the app on my phone. My phone doesn't show texts, they are white probably or transparent and also button's text color is different and also imageView is not showing.

I tested it on emulator and also different device but the same model and it is working. It was also working on my device, but now it doesn't. I rebooted my phone, reinstalled app and no solution happend.

Thank you for your help

My phone is Realme 8

Down is a picture of what it looks like on my phone and Android studio preview[image]

Comment: Try changing Day/Night mode of your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the night mode of the phone was doing all of the bad stuff. Thank you very much, I didn't realise that. I just turned off the night mode in the app and it is alright now.